# How can I convert a list of numbers to list of sums of numbers up to current element in python, using a functional approach?

Tags: python, functional-programming

To clarify, my original list contains the difference between two consecutive values, starting from zero. I want to convert this list to a list of actual values using a functional style, without having to keep a global state during calculation, without for loops, using map, reduce, etc.

```
my_list = [0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1]
result = my_function(my_list)

print(result)

[0, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

Comment: wow! this is awesome, thanks.

Comment: is there an inverse of this function that will output my_list given the result list?

Comment: @kureta `itertools.starmap(operator.sub, zip(a, [0] + a))`, but please, don't use this code anywhere. This is clearly not the pythonic way. Unclear, error-prone, dense.

Comment: how about this?
    
`def differences(seq):`
    `iterable, copied = tee(seq)`
    `next(copied)`
    `for x, y in zip(iterable, copied):`
        `yield y - x

Answer (score 3):

```
def my_function(lst):
    return [sum(lst[:i]) for i in range(len(lst))]
```